# ubuntu 20.04 sudenly using port 5432?

Tags: 20.04, docker, postgresql

I was using a postgres docker just fine with ubuntu 18.04.  Now I updated to ubuntu 20.04 and I suddenly can no longer start the docker, since the following error pops up - notice this error keeps appearing after freshly booting:

```
$ sudo docker start pg
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint pg (d188f0712e7079530a6d82eaf8c8770ca0ba8b755e41d87810a691e945725f52): listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use
Error: failed to start containers: pg
```

Now to see what process might be using that port I tried `netstat -nlp` however this gave the unhelpful line:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Indicating that "no PID/program name" is using that port. - What is causing ubuntu to block the common postgres port suddenly. And can I update either docker to use a different port or prevent ubuntu of blocking that port? (Without breaking stuff).

---

With `lsof` I find that a postgres database runs on that address: but what has changed with the update from 18.04 to 20.04 that suddenly this address is used? Can I find which tool is responsible for this?

```
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:5432
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postgres 1285 postgres    3u  IPv4  37282      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
```

---

`pstree -s 1285` (or correct version after rebooting) gives the following response:

```
systemd───postgres───6*[postgres]
```

hunting the startup processes using `sudo systemctl list-unit-files --type=service`

returns amongst the lines the following:

```
postgresql.service                         enabled         enabled      
postgresql@.service                        indirect        enabled
```

But this still doesn't give me a clue what caused the postgres service to start running on my pc (or what application is responsible).

Comment: Check with `sudo lsof -i tcp:5432`.

Comment: @waltinator added that to the post.

Comment: Have you checked this similar SO question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021678/docker-error-response-from-daemon-driver-failed-programming-external-connectiv

Comment: `pstree` should help here. Take the PID of whatever is listening (1285 in your example) and run: `pstree -s 1285`. Then add the output to your question. That should show us what is launching the 1285 process.